# XAMPP - Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: mysql, xampp

I downloaded downloading XAMPP for my learning lesson. After I finished the
install, I can use it normally. But when I try to connect to MySQL I keep return this error.

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST","localhost");
define("DB_USER","root");
define("DB_PWD","");
define("DB_DBNAME","text");
define("DB_CHARSET","utf8");

?>
function connect(){
    $link=mysql_connect("DB_HOST","DB_USER","DB_PWD") or die("连接失败Error:".mysql_error().":".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_DBNAME);
    return $link;
}
```

Comment: If you have the latest version of XAMPP bonded with PHP7 that function will not exist, as it has been deprecated since PHP5.5 ... You should be using PDO or mysqli_* functions ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, Kindly ensure the MySQL service is running.

- Open XAMPP Control Panel
- Click on Start button corresponding to MySQL module.

Then, Try checking to see if the PHP MySQL extension module is being loaded:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Run the above code/page and search for mysql.
If it's not there, add the following to the php.ini file:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Update: mysql_* functions have been removed in PHP 7. You probably have a php7 in XAMPP. Please use PDO or `mysqli_connect("DB_HOST","DB_USER","DB_PWD")` instead of `mysql_connect().`

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect(),hi i using ur way to recheck for few times but keep on this error also. I already active extension=php_mysql.dll

Comment: @philipngu Updated my answer. Please check if this can help. Use mysqli_connect.

Comment: Hi,i not yet trying for the last step that using mysqli. Before that sorry late updated your ans.

Answer (score 1):

First of all looking at your code; you have this part:

```
    function connect(){
        $link=mysql_connect("DB_HOST","DB_USER","DB_PWD") or die("连接失败Error:".mysql_error().":".mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(DB_DBNAME);
        return $link;
    }
```

After you have closed the php tag("?>"); meaning what comes after the closing php tag is not part of your php code. So try inserting the closing php tag at the end of your code. Something like this:

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST","localhost");
define("DB_USER","root");
define("DB_PWD","");
define("DB_DBNAME","text");
define("DB_CHARSET","utf8");

function connect(){
    $link=mysql_connect("DB_HOST","DB_USER","DB_PWD") or die("连接失败Error:".mysql_error().":".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_DBNAME);
    return $link;
}
?>
```

As for your code; I would simply rewrite it as:

```
    <?php
    $DB_HOST = "localhost"; 
    $DB_DBNAME = "text"; 
    $DB_USER = "root"; 
    $DB_PWD = ""; 

    $db_link = mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PWD) or die('连接失败Error:'.mysql_error());  
    mysql_select_db($DB_DBNAME, $db_link) or die('连接失败Error:'.mysql_error());
    ?>
```

Then try connecting to your MySQL database.

Comment: I found the problem and solve already. In php7 is not support for mysql as answer above. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was changing from the function call to the class initialization, as mentioned here https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/php/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect.html

From

```
$link = mysqli_connection($host, $user, $password, $db_name);

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

To

```
$link = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db_name);

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```