# How do i fix "Call to undefined function mysqli_init()" error

Tags: php, xampp

I wanted to test running a php function via CMD, but when i run `php index.php Cron test` i get:

```
    An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type:        Error
Message:     Call to undefined function mysqli_init()
Filename:    C:\xampp2\htdocs\flybyspace\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 135

Backtrace:
        File: C:\xampp2\htdocs\flybyspace\application\models\Booking_Model.php

C:\xampp2\htdocs\flybyspace>php index.php Cron test

     An uncaught Exception was encountered

     Type:        Error
     Message:     Call to undefined function mysqli_init()
     Filename:    C:\xampp2\htdocs\flybyspace\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php
     Line Number: 135

    Backtrace:
            File: C:\xampp2\htdocs\flybyspace\application\models\Booking_Model.php
            Line: 5
            Function: database

            File: C:\xampp2\htdocs\flybyspace\index.php
            Line: 315
            Function: require_once
```

the php function:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Cron extends CI_Controller
{

    public function test($to = 'World')
    {
        echo "Hello {$to}!".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

im using codeigniter and XAMPP for my local server and DB.
other answers on stackoverflow say i should uncomment `extension=mysqli` in php.ini but mine is already uncommented so that is not the correct solution in my case.

Comment: Might be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38124654/5754486 -> 

`extension=php_mysql.dll`

Comment: Make sure you're checking the correct php.ini. Many installations have a separate one for CLI and FPM. You can verify it by running `php -i` and looking for the mysqli section.

Comment: Well as `mysqli_init()` requires no parameter. The only think that could be wrong is that you have amended the wrong `php.ini` file. It has to be the one in the `Apache/bin` folder if this is coming from a web page

Comment: Although if you are writing a CRON, then maybe you should check the `php.ini` file in the `xampp\php\` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that i had 2 installations of XAMPP, the older vesion didn't have a php.ini file at all. adding the file fixt the problem.

all my files were in the htdocs folder of the second installation so i'm not sure how the older version affected my new one.